# Custom/separate categories for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

How can I achieve a separate "data space" for the categories of my custom post type?
I don't want the general post categories to appear in my custom post type and vice versa.

The `register_taxonomy` function seems to add a "tagging system" (bottom panel in the screen) to the post type but not the same small window the "real" categories have (upper panel in the screen).

[image: custom categories vs custom tags]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `register_taxonomy` to create a category-like custom taxonomy using the argument **'hierarchical'** set to true.

In [Codex example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Example) see the first taxonomy registered (*"Genres"*).